# Refresh DIV using partial view in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to refresh a div based on the dropdown selection. I have a main view which uses a partial view (_Module). The main view has a dropdown; upon selecting the dropdown I am trying to change the content in the partial view which in turn would be reflected on the main view.

The main view:

```
@model Test.Models.CreateDirectoryModel 
@{
ViewBag.Title = "CreateAdmin";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateAdmin", "RDBWeb", FormMethod.Post))
{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ProductType").change(function () {
            var catType = $(this).val();
            $("#result").load('@(Url.Action("GetPPOFlag", "RDBWeb", null, Request.Url.Scheme))?catType=' + catType);
        });
    });
</script>
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Create a New Directory</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DirectoryNumber, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DirectoryNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DirectoryNumber)
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductType, new SelectList(Model.ProductType), "Select Product")
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductType)
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DirectoryName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DirectoryName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DirectoryName)
        </div>
    </div>   
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AdminName, ViewBag.Drop as SelectList, "Select Admin")
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminName)
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="result">
        @if(Model.Module != null)
        {
            {Html.RenderPartial("_Module", Model.Module);}
        }
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>


    </div>
</div>  
}
```

The partial view is:

```
@model Test.Models.CreateDirectoryModel

@foreach (string s in Model.Module)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(a => s.ToString());
}
```

The methods relevant for these in the controller are:

```
    public ActionResult GetPPOFlag(string catType)
    {
        ProdTypeModel p1 = new ProdTypeModel();
        int flag = p1.GetPPOFlag(catType);
        return RedirectToAction("GetModule", new { flag = flag });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetModule(int flag)
    {
        ModuleType m1 = new ModuleType();
        List<string> moduleList= m1.GetModules(flag);
        return PartialView("_Module", moduleList);

    }
```

My problem is that by default the Partial view object is null initially as the dropdown value is yet to be chosen. I added a check to render the partial view only if the object is not null; but that does not load the new values into the partial view. All I see is that the GetModule method is invoked and the partial view method is called as well, but there is no change in the div on the main page nor the partial view.

Comment: what new values you expect to be loaded on the page load ? Also the `RenderPartial` call will not invoke your action method `GetModule`. Why do you think it is being called on the page load ?

Comment: @Shyju: Initially on page load the div should not have any value. Once a value is selected using the dropdown, the div should show the content based on the dropdown selection.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Is it making the ajax call ? Check your browser network tab

Comment: @Shyju: It does make a call as I can see the debugger activating for the GetPPOFlag method. The problem I feel is once I select a value from the drop down the partial view is not being populated.

Comment: may be you have an error in your partial view (or the action method which renders that. What is the response coming back (in your browser network tab) ? Is that a 200 response or 500 ? You can also try to access the url in a new browser tab to see the errors (if any) try `yourSite/RDBWeb/GetPPOFlag?catType=someValue`

Comment: @Shyju: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: That means there is an error in your code. We have no idea what it is. Put a breakpoint / try accessing the url in a new browser tab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127216/discussion-between-user2272525-and-shyju).

Comment: Thank you @Shyju :)

Answer (score 0):

try to do like this, just keep an empty div inside in the main view like this

```
    <div id="result">

     </div>
```

On dropdown selection change, give a ajax call and get partial view and render html in the div

```
    $('#result').empty();
    $("#result").html(data);
```